# Why can't I retrieve an attribute from the Model but I'm able to from JSP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm learning spring mvc and understand the use of the Model and ModelAttribute.  However, I can't retrieve the Model's attribute so I resorted to using the JSP param value.  What am I doing wrong? I checked the model still had a value for the attribute using `@ModelAttribute("username") User user / user.username` and sure enough it does.

Controller

```
 package login.user;

 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.ui.Model;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

 @Controller
 public class LoginUser {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showMenu()
    {
        return "menu";
    }

    @RequestMapping("login")
    public String loginUser(Model model)
    {
        User newUser = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", newUser);
        return "login-user";
    }

    @RequestMapping("processUser")
    public String processUser(Model model)
    {
        Option newOption = new Option();
        model.addAttribute("option", newOption);
        return "process-login";
    }
}
```

User

```
package login.user;

public class User {

    private String username;
    private char password[];

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public char[] getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(char[] password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

login-user.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login User</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form:form action="processUser" modelAttribute="user">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td>
                     <form:input path="username" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td>
                    <form:input type="password" path="password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="Login" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

process-login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form modelAttribute="option">
        <h3>Welcome ${param.username}.  Please choose an activity below</h3>  <---- changed from ${user.username}
        <div>   
            <form:select path="option">
                <form:option value="Email" label="Email"></form:option>
                <form:option value="Enter Recipe" label="Enter Recipe"></form:option>
                <form:option value="Retrieve Recipe" label="Retrieve Recipe"></form:option>
            </form:select>
        </div>
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your last `@RequestMapping` method as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("processUser")
    public String processUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model)
    {
        Option newOption = new Option();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("option", newOption);
        return "process-login";
    }
```

Now use ${user.username} in jsp.

Answer (score 1):

The spring model data is stored in the standard Java request scope. If you are trying to get the username, you need to add it in the request scope again. So, you can write the `processUser` method as follows.

```
@RequestMapping("processUser")
    public String processUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,Model model)
    {
        Option newOption = new Option();
         // do stuff with user data
        newOption.setUsername(user.getUsername()); 
        model.addAttribute("option", newOption);
        return "process-login";
    }
```

So, you should be able to get it in the jsp as `${option.username}`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the request scope constraint